# Setting up thttpd to run vqadmin or qmailadmin...keep getting 404s

Tags: cgi, thttpd

I run nginx for my web server but wanted to quickly toss up thttpd so I could do some maintainenace using either vqadmin or qmailadmin.

Those files are located at: /usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/qmailadmin and /usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/vqadmin/vqadmin.cgi.

My /etc/thttpd.conf is:

```
host=127.0.0.1
port=8000
user=apache
logfile=/var/log/thttpd.log
pidfile=/var/run/thttpd.pid
dir=/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin
nochroot
cgipat=**.cgi
```

When I use lynx to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/vqadmin/vqadmin.cgi, thttpd tosses a 404. Any idea how to get this working? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting a [404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), does not the logfile have any information on why thttpd cannot locate the cgi script?

Comment: the thttpd log just indicates the 404 and no additional info is in /var/log/messages

Comment: I think your directory directive should be dir=/usr/local/apache and not /usr/local/apache/cgi-bin